# Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'> ` error code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when I try to validations for each filed it does not work. instead of that it show about error. give me proper answer for that.
*views.py*

```
from moviList.models import moviListModel
from moviList.api.serializers import moviSerializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
# from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class movi_list(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        abc = moviSerializers(moviListModel.objects.all(), many = True)
        return Response(abc.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        abc = moviSerializers(data = request.data)
        if abc.is_valid():
            abc.save()
            return Response({'message' : 'you add the update infomation into your old one'})
```

*serializers.py file*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from moviList.models import moviListModel

        
class moviSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    year = serializers.IntegerField()
    country = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['name'] == data['country'] :
            raise serializers.ValidationError("this is real ")
        else:
            return data
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return moviListModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.year = validated_data.get('year', instance.year)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from moviList.api.views import movi_list

urlpatterns = [
    path('', movi_list.as_view()),
    # path('<int:pk>/', item)
]
```

both filed validation or object validations does not work with my simple situation

Comment: Well, what if `abc` is *not* valid? What does your view return then? (Hint: nothing.)

Comment: Your `post` does not return anything if the serializer is invalid.

Comment: @deceze return should be `return Response({'message' : 'this is just error message'})`. but it doesn't make any sense to this code...

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is (likely) because the serializer (`abc`) is not valid, in that case you return nothing, hence the error.

Likely your POST request is thus not sufficient, but it is hard to say. You however use too much boilerplate logic. You can use a `ListCreateAPIView` here:

```
class MovieListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = moviListModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = moviSerializers
```

You can also remove boilerplate by using a `ModelSerializer`:

```
class moviSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['name'] == data['country']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('this is real')
        return super().validate(data)
        
    class Meta:
        model = moviListModel
        fields = ('name', 'year', 'country')
```

Comment: thanks for your answare.. but in the invalid serializor I want to return `return serializers.ValidationError("this is real ")`. but it doesn't work. so how can I solve it... ?

Comment: @Gayashan: you need to return a HTTP response, you can not return a validation error in the view, since each HTTP request should be answered with a response. The way Django does this is a response with a status code in the 400-499 range that contains the validation error.